# vboxdrv kernel module

Tags: virtualbox, kernel-modules

I'm just install virtualbox and when i try to launch the program from the terminal 
i got this error

```
#virtualbox
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
 Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
 headers, most likely linux-headers-686.

 You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

I have try to run this command

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

but this error come

```
bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory
```

and then

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.12-kali1-686-pae
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.12-kali1-686-pae'
```

the version of kernel in the system when executing `uname -r` is

```
3.12-kali1-686-pae
```

however in the directory `/usr/src/` the version of the linux header is

```
linux-headers-3.14-kali1-686-pae
```

I have try to reinstall virtualbox-dkms too but not work

my question is why the version of the kernel is different from linux header? is there any solution to help fix this problem?

Comment: Did you do as it suggested and install the package: `virtualbox-dkms`? Also what distro is this?

Comment: You've installed the kernel some time ago and now that version has been replaced by the 3.14 one. That includes the linux-headers package. Update your kernel to match the linux-headers version.

Comment: I use kali linux distro and how do i update the kernel to match the kernel version?